# Chart.js horizontalBar customization

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, frontend, web-frontend

I'm trying to implement a horizontal bar graph with chartJS.
The prototype is this:

[image: img]

But I'm having problems with the implementation of negative values.
Can you give me some help on how I can use bars with different orientations on the same chart?

Comment: No way to create such a chart (Besides "cheating" and change axis label text by API & callbacks). Your chart ratios do not make sense (`100$` bar fill area does not make sense of VS `12,000$`). Also, no way to show negative values without negative axis. For the text above the bars use this plugin: https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.com/ -- Please add data example. Maybe first try to solve this from the data-visualization / design aspect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there's no way to create such a chart with chartJS framework. So I had to manipulate the chart data (and colors) with js to get the results.
If someone is interested in more details I'm available.

Answer (score 0):

Drawing bars with different orientation can be done with [**floating bars**](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/pull/6056). Individual bars are specified with the syntax `[min, max]`. This feature was introduced with [Chart.js v2.9.0](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/releases/tag/v2.9.0).

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById('canvas'), {
  type: 'horizontalBar',
  data: {
    labels: [1, 2, 3, 4],
    datasets: [{
      label: 'data',
      data: [[-3, 0], [0, 6], [-4, 0], [0, 5]],
      backgroundColor: ['red', 'blue', 'green', 'orange']
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    legend: {
      display: false
    },
    title: {
      display: false
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.9.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="canvas" height="90"></canvas>
```